# Numpy Array Erro Com dtype=numpy.uint8

Tags: python, numpy

O código abaixo funciona normalmente, contudo os elementos são "objetos".

```
M = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2,3,4]],dtype=object)
```

Contudo, ao executar o código abaixo, recebo a mensagem "setting an array element with a sequence".
A questão é: como fazer um array de INT que tem essa característica "[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2,3,4]"?

```
M = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2,3,4]],dtype=numpy.uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

funciona se os vetores tiverem o mesmo número de elementos

```
M = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], dtype=numpy.uint8)
```